# How to get the response from my server, and how can I access that data

Tags: objective-c, ios10, nsurlsession

i am not getting response from server side .following are my code. what kind of mistake pls tell me thanks in advance.

check my code:

```
//NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"Email\":\"%@\",\"FirstName\":\"%@\"}",user,fname];
NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://golf.42point5.com/API/Jsonapi.php?method=singup"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

//NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                          NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                           if(error == nil)
                                                          {

                                                              NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                                              NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                                          }

                                                      }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

Comment: what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: i am  not getting the response like:

Comment: @Manishpatel not getting the response like, is not what's the value of the NSError object `error`?

Comment: i am not getting the value of error because when i put debug point and run the app the debug point jump from  NSURLSessionDataTask to  [dataTask resume]; directly @larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not using https please add to your  **info.plist** :

```
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>golf.42point5.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```